# Sharepoint 2010 Designer Read Operation

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint-2010

I have created a SQL Server stored procedure that queries our TFS_Warehouse database. I would like to create an External Content Type for this stored procedure so that I can display the result in a list on a sharepoint page.

The stored procedure has two in parameters (@ReleaseId and @ProjectNodeType) and it performs a select on the warehouse based on those inputs which returns the CurrentWorkItemBK, WorkItemId and Description.

I am able to successfully create the Read List operation but I am having a hard time creating the Read operation it says I need for an external list. I've been trying to set it up in a similar fashion to how I setup the Read List operation but it keeps giving errors.

Any ideas as to what I need to do or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I have no idea how to solve your problem, but please post the actual error messages instead of just saying "it keeps giving errors". You also haven't explained exactly what you're doing to create the read operation, and mentioning the SQL Server version is usually helpful.

Comment: There aren't too many choices as far as it goes (an inputs page and a returns page). I was hoping there was some easy common thing I was missing (like I kept having similar problems with the Read List operation) until I added comparison filters to the input params. Then it would let me click 'Finish'. In the Read operation using the sproc inputs and outputs listed above I've tried pretty much all of the combinations I could. I'm using SQl Server 2008. I was able to get the business list part working with the just the Read List operation. Is it possible to even do a Read operation with a sproc?

Comment: And the errors, depending on whether I map the 'identifier' CurrentWorkItemBK either says I ahve too many indexes or not enough.